# C++ Function call missing argument list

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
class Klasa
{
public:
    void petla(void* Args)
    {
        time_t tWait = clock() + 4 * CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        for(;;)
        {
            cout << "Test dzialania watkow" << endl;
            Sleep(1000);
        }
        _endthread();
    }
};
void main()
{
    Klasa* pKlasa = new Klasa;
    time_t tCzas = clock() + 10 * CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    _beginthread(pKlasa->petla, 0, NULL);
    while(tCzas>=clock())
    {
        cout << " Dziala" << endl;
        Sleep(500);
    }
    getch();
}
```

Error   1   error C3867: 'Klasa::petla': function call missing argument list; use '&Klasa::petla' to create a pointer to member c:\users\bartek\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\wątki\wątki\source.cpp    26  1   Wątki

This is an error and I don't know What shoud I do cause I can't put `()` in this                                                                                           `beginthread(pKlasa->petla, 0, NULL);`
Guys please help me :C

Comment: Try to make Klasa::petla static and then call _beginthread(&Klasa::petla, 0, NULL);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Klasa::petla` needs to be declared static if you want it to be the entry point of a thread.

The typical idiom for starting a thread within an object without leaking access to anything important or thread-dangerous looks something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <time.h>

class Klasa
{
public:
    void Start();

private:
    static void ThreadEntry(void *p);
    void ThreadBody();
};

void Klasa::Start()
{
    _beginthread(Klasa::ThreadEntry, 0, this);
}

void Klasa::ThreadEntry(void *p)
{
    ((Klasa *) p)->ThreadBody();
    _endthread();
    return;
}

void Klasa::ThreadBody()
{
    // do threaded action here
    time_t tWait = clock() + 4 * CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    for(;;)
    {
        cout << "Test dzialania watkow" << endl;
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}

void main()
{
    Klasa k;
    k.Start();

    time_t tCzas = clock() + 10 * CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    while(tCzas>=clock())
    {
        cout << " Dziala" << endl;
        Sleep(500);
    }

    char c;
    c << std::cin; // stick to either cin/cout or C-style IO, not both
}
```

At least, that's how I tend to do it using pthreads.  I'd imagine it's basically the same with windows threads.

Also, please try to avoid using [Hungarian Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation).  It's personal preference, but there are a lot of good arguments for not using it (like the fact that C++ is strongly typed and the type of every variable or function is apparent from its definition).

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
uintptr_t _beginthread( 
   void( *start_address )( void * ),
   unsigned stack_size,
   void *arglist 
);
```

So that function takes a *pointer to function*, and **not** a *pointer-to-member*. You can't convert between the two.

Either use a `static` member function (which is tied to the class instead of an instance) or create a non-member function.

Comment: Technically, member functions are still functions.  It basically comes down to the fact that non-static member functions mean nothing without an instance of the class they are defined for.  It doesn't make sense to try to call one without an object, and due to the implicit handling of `this`, the compiler won't let you try.

Comment: @Wug Don't teach me C++. I know the reason behind this, I just don't want to use incorrect or loose wording.

Comment: You didn't post this answer for yourself.  I know you know C++.  Others who read this won't.

Answer (score 2):

You must pass an address of function.

You cannot write though

```
_beginthread(&(pKlasa->petla), 0, NULL);
```

because `_beginthread` wants pointer to a function, not a pointer to an object's method.
Define a plain function with the required signature:

```
void threadfunc(void *data) {
  reinterpret_cast<Klasa*>(data)->petla();
}
```

and then begin a new thread with

```
_beginthread(threadfunc, 0, pKlasa);
```

Comment: Well, regardless of what `_beginthread` wants, `&(pKlasa->petla)` is invalid by itself. C++ does not support obtaining pointer-to-member pointers through member access expressions. The only way to obtain a member pointer is `&Klasa::petla`.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::thread(&Klasa::petla, pKlasa);
```

if you don't have a C++11 library you can do the same with Boost.